# react-native-push-notification not repeat local schedule notification on the 2nd day

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I setup local schedule notification with the day in future, the notification work on the 1st time but wont work on the 2nd day, the notification still return when i call getScheduledLocalNotifications() and the date is already set in the future, I'm testing on samsung s10e one ui 3.0

NOTE: the notification is runnning fine in background

I'm using RN 0.63.4 and react-native-push-notification@7.2.1

Here the code to reproduce

LocalPushController.js

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import { NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID } from "@env";
import { GET_NOTIS } from "../store/remiders/reminders.action";

export const PushNotificationInit = () => {
  PushNotification.configure({
    // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
    onNotification: function (notification) {
      console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
      console.log(dayjs(notification.firedate).format("HH:mm DD/MM/YYYY"));
      // console.log(
      //   new Date(notification.fireDate).getHours(),
      //   new Date(notification.fireDate).getMinutes()
      // );
      // process the notification

      // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
      notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
    },
    popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: true,
  });

  PushNotification.createChannel(
    {
      channelId: NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID || "scheduleLocal", // (required)
      channelName: "Gywreb Reminder", // (required)
      channelDescription: "A channel to categorise your notifications", // (optional) default: undefined.
      soundName: "default", // (optional) See `soundName` parameter of `localNotification` function
      importance: 4,
      vibrate: true, // (optional) default: true. Creates the default vibration patten if true.
    },
    (created) => console.log(`createChannel returned '${created}'`) // (optional) callback returns whether the channel was created, false means it already existed.
  );
};

export const LocalScheduleNotification = (date, id, notiConfig) => {
  const { description, title, repeatType } = notiConfig;
  console.log(date);
  // console.log(notiConfig);

  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    id,
    channelId: NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID || "scheduleLocal",
    bigText: description,
    title,
    message: "Expand to see more details",
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 200,
    playSound: true,
    soundName: "default",
    date,
    repeatType,
    autoCancel: false,
    number: 10,
    allowWhileIdle: true,
  });
};

export const GetLocalScheduleNotifications = (dispatch) => {
  let notiList = [];
  PushNotification.getScheduledLocalNotifications((notis) => {
    notiList = [...notis];
    dispatch({ type: GET_NOTIS, payload: notis });
  });
  return notiList;
};

export const CancelLocalScheduleNotification = (id) => {
  PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: "" + id });
};
```

ReminderEditScreen.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import AppFormField from "../components/AppFormField";
import { Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ADD_REMINDER } from "../store/remiders/reminders.action";
import AppFormDatePicker from "../components/AppFormDatePicker";
import DateTimeModalPicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { LocalScheduleNotification } from "../services/LocalPushController";
import moment from "moment";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import AppFormPicker from "../components/AppFormPicker";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import calcNext, { addDate, isScheduleBehind } from "../utils/calcSchedule";

const initialValues = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  isDatePick: false,
  isTimePick: true,
  isRepeat: false,
};

const options = [
  { label: "Daily", value: "day" },
  { label: "Weekly", value: "week" },
  { label: "Monthly", value: "month" },
];

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  title: Yup.string().required().min(4).label("Title"),
  description: Yup.string().label("Description"),
  isDatePick: Yup.boolean().label("Date"),
  isTimePick: Yup.boolean().oneOf([true], "You must choose the reminded time"),
  isRepeat: Yup.boolean().label("Repeat"),
});

const ReminderEditScreen = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { lastId } = useSelector((state) => state.reminders);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()));
  const [time, setTime] = useState(dayjs().add(5, "minutes").toDate());
  const [pickSchedule, setPickSchedule] = useState(
    dayjs().add(5, "minutes").toDate()
  );
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("time");
  const [repeatValue, setRepeatValue] = useState(options[0].value);
  const [minDate, setMinDate] = useState(new Date(Date.now()));

  const handleAddReminder = (values) => {
    const validId = lastId + 1;

    console.log(pickSchedule);

    const notiConfig = {
      title: values.title,
      description: `${values.description}`,
      repeatType: values.isRepeat ? repeatValue : null,
    };

    LocalScheduleNotification(pickSchedule, validId, notiConfig);
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_REMINDER,
      payload: {
        ...values,
        id: validId,
        repeatType: values.isRepeat
          ? options.find((type) => type.value === repeatValue).label
          : null,
        date: dayjs(pickSchedule).format(),
      },
    });

    navigation.navigate("Home");
  };

  const handleOpenPicker = (mode) => {
    setMode(mode);
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const handleDatePick = (date) => {
    const pickDate = moment(date);
    const pickTime = moment(time);
    const newDate = new Date(
      pickDate.year(),
      pickDate.month(),
      pickDate.date(),
      pickTime.hours(),
      pickTime.minutes(),
      pickTime.seconds(),
      pickTime.milliseconds()
    );
    setPickSchedule(newDate);
    setDate(date);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const handleTimePick = (time) => {
    let calcDate = date;
    if (isScheduleBehind(dayjs(time), dayjs())) {
      setMinDate(addDate(dayjs()).toDate());
      calcDate = addDate(dayjs(date)).toDate();
    } else {
      setMinDate(dayjs().toDate());
    }
    const pickDate = moment(calcDate);
    const pickTime = moment(time);
    const newDate = new Date(
      pickDate.year(),
      pickDate.month(),
      pickDate.date(),
      pickTime.hours(),
      pickTime.minutes(),
      pickTime.seconds(),
      pickTime.milliseconds()
    );
    setPickSchedule(newDate);
    setTime(time);
    setDate(calcDate);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaProvider style={styles.container}>
        <Formik
          initialValues={initialValues}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
          onSubmit={handleAddReminder}
        >
          {({ handleSubmit, setFieldValue, values }) => {
            return (
              <>
                <AppFormField name="title" placeholder="Title" />
                <AppFormField
                  name="description"
                  placeholder="Description"
                  numberOfLines={3}
                />
                <AppFormDatePicker
                  pickerMode="time"
                  icon="calendar-clock"
                  value={dayjs(time).format("HH:mm")}
                  name="isTimePick"
                  onOpen={handleOpenPicker}
                  title="Set Time"
                  onToggle={() =>
                    setFieldValue("isTimePick", !values["isTimePick"])
                  }
                />
                <AppFormDatePicker
                  pickerMode="date"
                  icon="calendar-today"
                  value={dayjs(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}
                  name="isDatePick"
                  onOpen={handleOpenPicker}
                  title="Set Date"
                  onToggle={() =>
                    setFieldValue("isDatePick", !values["isDatePick"])
                  }
                />
                <AppFormPicker
                  options={options}
                  title="Repeat"
                  icon="calendar-refresh"
                  name="isRepeat"
                  onToggle={() =>
                    setFieldValue("isRepeat", !values["isRepeat"])
                  }
                  onPick={(item) => setRepeatValue(item)}
                  selectedValue={repeatValue}
                />
                <DateTimeModalPicker
                  is24Hour={true}
                  minimumDate={minDate}
                  mode={mode}
                  isVisible={visible}
                  onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
                  onConfirm={mode === "date" ? handleDatePick : handleTimePick}
                />
                <Button
                  title="REMIND ME"
                  onPress={handleSubmit}
                  buttonStyle={styles.button}
                />
              </>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 15,
  },
});

export default ReminderEditScreen;
```

index.js

```js
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";
import { PushNotificationInit } from "./src/services/LocalPushController";

PushNotificationInit();

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: any answer ? because right now i m on your place :(

Comment: stuck on the same issue - but for ios. not getting the 2nd notification

Comment: just figure out somethings, it may relate to the OEM , mine is samsung one-ui 3 and its smart manager kill my app everyday at 2 a.m regardless i had my app ignored in battery optimization :v , i had to manually turn it off

Comment: hope this site help someone has the same prob dontkillmyapp.com